# Initialising Realm 5.0.x in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I've been using Realm in an application for a number of months, accessing the data using Realm Browser. I have used a simple set-up without encryption:

```
        do {
        _ = try Realm()
        } catch {
            print("Error initialising realm, \(error)")
        }
```

After upgrading to Realm 5.0.x I could no longer access the data - every time I tried to use the Realm Browser I was asked to enter the encryption key. I regressed to 4.4.x and all is OK again. I am using the latest version of the Browser available on the App Store.

Is this a new 'feature' in Realm 5, and should I now be using a different method to initialise the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've installed the new Realm 5.0 in your app, your database will be updated to match, format v10 - see the [5.0.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v5.0.0)

Therefore, if you're using Realm Studio 10.0 or less, you won't be able to open the Realm.

Likewise if you open a Realm with [Realm Studio 11.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases/tag/v3.11.0), it will upgrade your Realm as well.

- File format: Generates Realms with format v10 (Reads and upgrades all previous formats)
- Realm Object Server: 3.21.0 or later.
- Realm Studio: 3.11 or later.
- APIs are backwards compatible with all previous releases in the 5.x.y series.

So bottom line is as of now, RealmSwift 5.0.x is a match for Realm Studio 11+. Once you have your Realm stuff on the same page, initialization is the same so your code is fine.

Note that for Realm Studio 11.0

> When opening a file which is using an older format, you will get
>   prompted to upgrade (and optionally backup) the Realm file. NOTE: Once
>   the file has been upgraded, there is no way to downgrade it again and
>   it can only be used by the SDKs that support Realm file format v10.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I've been using Realm Browser (Version 3.0.1) downloaded from the App Store rather than Realm Studio. This does not seem to be compatible with Realm 5.

Comment: @MacMews Realm Browser was depreciated a couple of years ago. Realm Studio is the replacement. Browser will definitely not work for more modern Realm files so best to stick with Studio. If you installed the 5.0 API and got Realm Studio (from the links I provided) you should be good to go. Let me know.

Comment: thanks for your guidance. I didn't realise that the Browser had been depreciated. I have now downloaded the Studio and all is running well on Realm 5 :-)